# NuGet (non-)deployment of dll.config file in lib folder of System.Data.SQLite.Core Package?

Tags: nuget, app-config, nuget-package-restore, system.data.sqlite

## Question

What is the meaning of the package author of System.Data.SQLite packaging a `.dll.config` file in such a way that it is *included* in the output directory by the default(?) NuGet mechanism, when the same puts a comment into the file that you should *not* copy the file to the output directory??

Is it possible to *prevent* NuGet/MSBuild/VisualStudio to copy said file to the output directory?

**That is, is it possible to prevent a "related" file from `nupkg\lib\net46` being copied to the output directory?**

## Details

The [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) NuGet package contains the `System.Data.SQLite.dll` file (among other things), as well as the additional files `System.Data.SQLite.xml`and `System.Data.SQLite.dll.config`.

These three files are located in all `\lib\<framework>\` folders of the `nupkg`.

Accordingly, Visual Studio / MSBuild / NuGet copies these files to the output folder:

```
8>  Primary reference "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.111.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139". (TaskId:102)
8>      Resolved file path is "c:\...\nuget\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll". (TaskId:102)
8>      Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:102)
8>      Found related file "c:\...\nuget\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.xml". (TaskId:102)
8>      Found related file "c:\...\nuget\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll.config". (TaskId:102)
...
8>          c:\kse\nuget\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll.config
8>                  CopyLocal=true
8>                  FusionName=
8>                  HintPath=c:\...\nuget\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll
8>                  OriginalItemSpec=c:\...\nuget\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.111.0\lib\net46\System.Data.SQLite.dll
8>                  ResolvedFrom={HintPathFromItem}
8>                  Version=1.0.111.0
```

**However** [this file](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/finfo?name=NuGet/shared/Core/lib/System.Data.SQLite.dll.config&ci=trunk) contains a disclaimer:

> ```
>  * System.Data.SQLite.dll.config -
>  *
>  * WARNING: This XML configuration file is intended for use within the NuGet
>  *          package directories only.  Please do not copy this file to any of
>  *          the build output directories because it could interfere with the
>  *          native library pre-loading feature.
> ```

-- that it should *not* be copied. So: how do I *not* copy it? Should I care?

Note that [System.Data.SQLite.dll.config seems to be better documented under a different path.](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/finfo?name=System.Data.SQLite/Configurations/System.Data.SQLite.dll.config&ci=c37b617ed1ece85f)

Comment: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/bd9c4375cc03d8c6de81ea4fd63521a42e18682f

Answer (score 1):

If you reference NuGet packages with `PackageReference`, you can exclude assets from being imported into your project with the `ExcludeAssets` attribute as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) in section "Controlling Dependency Assets". However, this excludes a group of assets and does not allow for controlling single files and will not solve this problem.

Apart from that you could employ custom MS Build logic or try to delete the `.config` files with a post build event, which would both be similiar in the result.